# Set computer names as variables when using 'net view' in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I get most of my answers from this site when it comes to Batch, but this time
I'm stuck. I really don't know how I would go about doing this. I want it to list all the computers found in the network apart from the computer it is running on, using the net view command.

```
net view
SET //PCUser = %pc1%

echo %pc1%
```

I want the program to list the pc names in a list so it can do more than one at a time.

```
echo %pc1%
echo %pc2%
echo %pc3%
```

Then write them to a `txt` file so that next time it runs it will read the names from the `txt` file and exclude all the computers it found previously.

Comment: @wjl, [please **do not** add "thanks" to posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/135887).

Comment: Thanks @Charles. I didn't add that but I'll be sure to edit it out in the future.

Comment: The [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23917940/revisions) says that you *re*-added it.  Please be careful!

Comment: @Charles Looks like we edited it at the same time. I've never seen that happen before. I'll keep an eye out for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "alreadyDone=%~dp0\alreadyDone.txt"
    if not exist "%alreadyDone%" > "%alreadyDone%" echo(### List of processed computers ###

    set "counter=0"
    for /f %%a in (
        'net view ^| findstr /b /c:"\\\\" ^| findstr /g:"%alreadyDone%" /v'
    ) do (

        set /a "counter+=1"
        set "pc!counter!=%%a"

        >> "%alreadyDone%" echo(%%a
    )

    set pc

    endlocal
```

This uses a file to store the list of processed pcs. This list is used as a source of strings so in each call `findstr` can filter the list of machines retrieved from `net view`

`%counter%` is used to increment the name of the variable that will hold the name of the computers. In each iteration of the `for` loop, it is incremented and a new variable is assigned the retrieved value.

At the end of the loop, `set` command is used to echo to console the list of defined `pc...` variables holding the computer names.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, i was wondering how i would set it to not have the 'pc1=' bit because after it has finished scanning for other computers it enters the found computers into a command and it wouldn't work like that.

Comment: @user3683977, sorry, i am not sure of understanding it. Do you mean you don't want the console output? If it is the case, just remove the `set pc` line from code.

Comment: if i remove set pc from the code nothing comes up at all

Comment: @user3683977, so, what is what you need? is it the output list, the variables with the incremental index, both or something different?

Comment: Just so when i type %alreadydone% i just get the computer name.